# Securing a public REST API used by one app

Tags: rest, api, security

I need to build a REST API that will be used by one private SPA web application. The problem is that the REST API must be on a different server than the SPA, so it must allow CORS. For two layers of security, the API can require Basic Authentication over SSL plus check for the correct client IP address.

It will not be possible to have a user login process for the API, since it is a service used by the SPA. The user is already logged into the client that hosts the SPA. I will not have access to anything other than the user's ID, and the REST API will have no way to validate this user ID.

Because the user is logged into the client's server, the API can be restricted to requests from the SPA's IP address, but that still potentially could allow anyone on that server to use the API other than the SPA.

Is this adequate protection?

I am considering adding a third layer of protection in the way of an access token, but this would be also fairly simple to uncover.  If you know the basic authentication information (easily obtainable) and your IP address matches the expected client IP, then you are able to call the API to get an access token.

Also, with an access token comes the complexity of dealing with expired tokens.

Is it impossible to completely secure an API that requires a web-based client?

How many layers of security are enough?

Comment: I think it would be best for your SPA to make server-side API requests. That way you don't need to enable CORS on the REST API and a client on the SPA can't sniff the traffic going to the API (include security headers).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury to add server-side code.